# Float Icons right on navbar (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to get a home icon to appear to the right of my nav bar. For some reason floating and aligning are not working (I tried with display flex and block). I am not too sure why and I was hoping someone could help me with this issue as I am not really sure where to start, as I am not to sure how much more to explain the issue.

Any help would be grand.

```css
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    background-color: #042439;
}

#logo-sector {
    width: 100%;
    height: 195px;
    display:flex;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

nav, a{
    background-color: #05304C !important;
    color: whitesmoke !important;
}

a:hover{
    text-transform: capitalize !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#logo{
    width: auto;
    height: 110%;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-self: center;
}

.logo-sector-right{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    align-self: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span><img id="hamburger-icon" src="./img/dropdown.png" width="25" style=""></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Landing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Payment</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Apply</a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Non-collapsing right-side icons -->
            <ul class="" style="display: block; float: right;">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-cog"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-home"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You just need to use the `.ms-auto` class in the ul. So replace `<ul class="" style="display: block; float: right;">` with `<ul class="ms-auto">`.